# Angular 2 return html instead of string

Tags: html, angular

Let's assume I have a `test` property like that:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    testing = '<strong>Just testing</strong>';

}
```

And I add to my test.component.html this line:

```
{{ testing }}
```

The output will be `<strong>Just testing</strong>`. I want it to return **Just Testing**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` for this:

```
<span [innerHTML]="testing"></span>
```